# Testsaslauthd: Connect() connection refused in Ubuntu machine

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ldap, sasl

I am trying to test saslauthd for mongodb in ubuntu machine. 
Executed the following cmd:

```
testsaslauthd -u "xxx" -p "xxx" -f /var/run/saslauthd/mux/
```

It shows as follows:0: No "authentication failed"

Please let me know how to resolve this.Thanks in advance.